# Python Console asking for importing sys in PyCharm (Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

Whenever I run this code it asks to **import sys**. It stopped before i can give input in that code.

[PyCharm stopped whenever i tried to run this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed6JR.png)

Comment: Yes...you asked for input. You have to enter it in the console (in the MyCode tab at the bottom). The program will block until you (as the user) enter the values.

Comment: Thank You @MattMessersmith Finally it works for me.